# LINQ to Entities query for count and group by with join on 2 tables

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I need a LINQ to Entities query or lambda expression for the following statement.

```
SELECT 
    at.Name,
    Count(a.AssetTypeId) as CountofAssets,
    at.AssetTypeId
FROM
    AssetTypes at, Assets a
WHERE
    at.AssetClassId = 7
GROUP BY
    at.Name,at.AssetTypeID
```

Comment: Is it intentional that you are performing a cross join?

Comment: Edit:
I forgot to add a where clause for the tables.. please see the changed SQL statement below
 SELECT  
    at.Name, 
    Count(a.AssetTypeId) as CountofAssets, 
    at.AssetTypeId 
FROM 
    AssetTypes at, Assets a 
WHERE 
    at.AssetClassId = 7  and 
    at.AssetTypeId = a.AssetTypeId
GROUP BY 
    at.Name,at.AssetTypeID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var assetTypes = context.AssetTypes.Where(a => a.AssetClass.Id == 7).Select(a => new { a.Name, a.AssetTypeId, CountOfAssets = a.Asset.Count()).ToList();
```

I hope you have foreign keys in your base and model graph is created properly.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Lukled.. The model graph has the proper associations and your solution works